# How do I filter a text range in powerbi?

Tags: filter, text, powerbi, dax

For instance, I have a table that has values such as '00001', '00023', 00145', '00213', '05345', 08966', etc. I want to have 2 textboxes (or some slicer) where I put '00000' and '00300'. It should return the table with columns that have '00023', '00145', and '00213'. I can't find a filter like that.

I tried using the following DAX:

```
    CALCULATETABLE (
        TableA,
        TableA[ColumnC] >= "00000" && TableA[ColumnC] <= "00300"
    )
```

But that doesn't work either. It just returns the entire table.

Comment: Can you duplicate that column and convert it to a number? Then you can filter and sort by the the numeric version. (Just use the Sort By Column in table view)